# Implementing SSO And Data Synchronization

Tags: mysql, synchronization, single-sign-on, liferay, cas

I am required to implement SSO between Liferay and a number of PHP-based systems. Database used is MySQL.

CAS will authenticate through Liferay user database, as well as through user database from System A and System B. The reason why each system use different user database is because they were developed by different teams, perhaps different vendors.

It is up to me to decide the master table that will be used to store all login information and permissions to all systems.

My question is, how do I synchronize data between tables in different databases? When a record is inserted into systemA.userdb, it will be automatically inserted into master.table (the most important column being the username and password). So does update and delete.

Do I have to use trigger, or is there any software for it? Any advice on my SSO implementation will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest creating a VIEW for each application that puts the user table in whatever format they expect.

if for some reason you can't get a view to do what you need, then the next best option would be a trigger.

if the applications use different mysql servers, combine either of the two above with federated tables.